# asp using select2 libraries don't work on server controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in my asp.net project but it not working on server controls. My code is here

```
<select id="selServiceArea" runat="server">
   <option value="volvo" selected="selected">Select service Area </option>
</select>
```

and jquery is here

```
$('#selServiceArea').select2({ placeholder: 'Find and Select Books' });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you define was "not working" means?

Comment: when remove runat ="sever" then work fine. but we need its id to use in its  c# code for retrieving data from database.

Comment: here is my c# code :                                                                      dataLayer dl = new dataLayer();
            DataTable dt = dl.SelectMethod("Select name from service_area"); 
            selServiceArea.DataSource = dt;
            selServiceArea.DataValueField = "name";
            selServiceArea.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Change the select element to an asp:Dropdownlist, and use the clientidmode property set to static, for example:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="selServiceArea" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
```

I'm thinking when this is rendered, your runat=server is causing .net to change the value of the id in the DOM.